# Will a motor with 1,16 Nm rotate a 50 mm gear moving about 12 kg

Tags: mechanical-engineering, motors, torque

I'm not an expert in mechanics, so this is my question.

I will buy the motor of the image below to move my door.

In the motor shaft, there is a gear with 50 mm of diameter which will move the door.

The power you does to move the door is similar to lift 12 kg.

The speed needed is about **0,3 m/s.**

So, can this motor move the door?

The text are in Portuguese.

Corrente = Current.

[image: Motor Details]

And here is more details of the mechanics, is the idea:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to give us more details of the mechanical system. FOr example, is there a chain on the other end of the gear? Or another gear? And how fast do you want the move the door?

Comment: More details added, thanks

Comment: Please clarify whether the 12 kg is mass or force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The force required to lift 12 kg against gravity is 12 × 9.81 = 120 N (approx).
- Your gear radius = 25 mm = 0.025 m.
- To drive the load you would need a torque of 120 N × 0.025 m = 3 Nm (ignoring all losses).

Your motor specification is 1.16 Nm.

**:^(**

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If you can counter-balance the door you may get away with the 1.16 Nm motor.

Answer (score 0):

The relation of torque with force is,

$$\tau= F*r \quad 1.16Nm =12*9.8*r \\ r= 1.16/117.6=0.00986m=0.986cm$$

- $\tau$ = torque
- f=12kg(g)= 12*9.8=117.6N
- r= radius of the pully= 0.986cm

So your 5cm=2.5cm radius pulley can not move your door. Either you need to replace it with the small size pulley or you have to use a gear with $r= 2.5/0.986* 2.5=6.33cm \text{ or a diameter of 12.67cm } \ $ engaged with your 50mm pulley.